# Asp.net get account names from outlook express

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook-2010

I have created an application for listing account names connected to outlook express. It runs successfully when running from visual studio, but it is not working after publishing on iis.

Here is my Code :

```
public static DataTable GetCompleteAccountNames()
    {
        DataTable dt = ERPCommonMethods.CreateDataTable(new string[] { "AccountName" });

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace _ns;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application _application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        _ns = _application.Session;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folders objCompleteAccounts = _ns.Folders;
        DataRow dr = null;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder objSingleAccount in objCompleteAccounts)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["AccountName"] = objSingleAccount.Name;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt.Select("", "AccountName ASC").CopyToDataTable();
    }
```

after publishing on iis, the following error occures...

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

can any one help me....

Comment: Thanks, I Found solution myself : Change Application Pool Identity To Custom Account and use username as Compute Name\User Name and password as system password

Comment: The Outlook Express Should Be Closed And IIS Must Be Restarted Before Running Hosted Application.